# Ubuntu Reboot for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server 64 bit on linode. I am using Elasticsearch as a service  , rabbitmq , Celery .

The problem is after having my instance running for 4 months and 21 days suddenly elasticsearch failed to start. When I reboot the ubuntu it appears to be working correctly.

Now the question is , what is the standard interval/time  to reboot a ubuntu server which is deployed in production ?

Should I also reboot the ubuntu after 4/5 months ? How the big production systems handle the maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If everything would work ok and you don't update any programs you would not need to reboot. So the advice is: analyze. Look in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was like, when not enough memory in the jvm

Es configuration: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html